# CXF: Difference between PAYLOAD and MESSAGE data formats

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-camel

I started working with Apache Camel and CXF.

In the "cxf:cxfEndpoint" configuration, what is the difference between dataFormat = PAYLOAD and dataFormat = MESSAGE?

I thought in both cases a org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload is passed into the Camel Exchange, no?

So is MESSAGE simply the body of a PAYLOAD (-> PAYLOAD without Header and Attachment) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. CXF MESSAGE mode applies no SOAP processing, only body extraction. PAYLOAD mode allows for headers etc.

The official documentation is quite clear in this case, refer to:

http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html#CXF-HowtogetandsetSOAPheadersinPAYLOADmode

Comment: The more important question (for me) is: "I thought in both cases a org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload is passed into the Camel Exchange, no?"